# Argument of type '() => Timeout' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to clear a timeout with React and TypeScript on `componentWillUnmount` but am getting the following error:

`Argument of type '() => Timeout' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)`

Here is my code:

```js
  startPolling = (): ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> => setTimeout(() => this.loadData(), this.getTimeout());

  componentWillUnmount = (): void => {
    clearTimeout(this.startPolling); // error is thrown here
  }
```

I'm stumped as to how to get rid of this error. What is the problem with my code? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that `clearTimeout()` expects a number, but you are passing in a function. [The MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) says the parameter is "the identifier of the timeout you want to cancel." [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns an id that can be used here. You need to save the return value to use later when you call `clearTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `startPolling` definition is for a function. You want to pass the result of calling this function to `clearTimeout`, not the function itself. I'm guessing you intended to call `startPolling` on `componentDidMount`.